# Selective children component render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

A basic question I need help here.
Whenever this.setState invoked at parent components, all the children components will be rendered. This will cause the performance issue if I have huge amount of child components.

Lets give an example,

**Parent Component**

```
handleToggleTick() {
    const newObj = Object.assign({}, this.state, { iconName: ''});
    this.setState({
      iconName: newObj.iconName,
    });
}

render() {
  return(
    <ChildComponentA iconName={this.state.iconName} toggleTick={() => this.handleToggleTick}></ChildComponentA>
    <ChildComponentB></ChildComponentA>
    <ChildComponentC></ChildComponentA>
  )
}
```

Based on the example above, whenever handleToggleTick invoked from childcomponentA, setState invoked for new iconName. What I want is, **only ChildComponentA only the one get render** since props.iconName is related to it, but not for childcomponentB and childcomponentC.

I understand there is an option to check shouldComponentUpdate in childcomponent to prevent it get render. But, imagine I have over 100 of childcomponent, would it be frustrating to write over 100 times of shouldComponentUpdate method?

I need help here, please advice!

Comment: Try using `React.memo` on the child components (`export default React.memo(MyComp)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React doesn't provide any way to render children selectively. The component will either render or not. But I need to highlight a few points why this is not a problem when we use React in practice.

First of all, you don't need to manually implement `shouldComponentUpdate` for each component. If you don't want to rerender component if its props and state haven't changed, you can just extend from the [`PureComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) class instead of the `Component` class. Note that `React.PureComponent's` `shouldComponentUpdate()` only uses shallow comparison for state and props. But this shouldn't be a problem if you follow react best practices and avoid mutating the state.

Also, it's not practical to have more than 100 **different** components in one render method. React always encourages decomposing your UI into smaller components and using component composition. When we follow this approach, components will be nested inside each other in different levels instead of having a large number of components in one render method.[image]

*What I'm trying to explain is it's more practical and easy to manage when we compose our component in a nested fashion (2) rather than having lots of components inside a big container component (1).*

In your example, if ChildComponentB and ChildComponentC are inside another component called ChildConatainerComponent then we only need to implement `shouldComponentUpdate()` for ChildConatainerComponent. Then it will automatically stop rendering any child element inside it.

```
render() {
  return(
    <ChildComponentA iconName={this.state.iconName}
      toggleTick={() => this.handleToggleTick}/>
    <ChildConatainerComponent/>
  )
}

class ChildConatainerComponent extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <ChildComponentB/>
       <ChildComponentC/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Another very import concept to keep in mind is calling `render` function doesn't mean that React recreates all the DOM elements again. The `render` method only make changes to React virtual DOM which is an in-memory representation of DOM and it's faster than actual DOM. Then React compare versions of virtual DOM which are before the update and after the update and the actual DOM will be updated with only what has actually changed.

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea now.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you could consider is moving `iconName` into `ChildComponentA`, considering this is the only component related to it.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for fast reply. But my design is, parent component act as container, for childcompoent A is my dumb component. so, dumb component only act for presentation, parent component should handle the state.

Comment: I see. Then I believe you will have to use `shouldComponentUpdate`.